# want to convert datetime to format like mm/yyyy

Tags: c#, datetime

I want to grab the datetime object in string form such as "mm/yyyy"

```
ViewBag.Created = d.item.StartDate.ToString("mm/yyyy");
```

but I am getting string as 10-2012. Please help me to overcome this issue.

Comment: Not really sure about your problem, but for month it should be `MM` (uppercase M), lower case `mm` is for minutes

Answer (score 2):

Format for month, should be in `MM`, `mm` is for minutes

```
 ViewBag.Created = d.item.StartDate.ToString("MM/yyyy", 
                                              CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: That will still give "-" rather than "/" though, assuming the original post is accurate. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

`mm` is minutes, and `/` is the **culture-specific** date separator. It sounds like in the current culture, `-` is the date separator. I suspect you want `MM/yyyy`, using the invariant culture, which has `/` as the separator:

```
ViewBag.Created = d.item.StartDate.ToString("MM/yyyy",
                                            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Alternatively, you could just quote the slash:

```
ViewBag.Created = d.item.StartDate.ToString("MM'/'yyyy");
```

Note that this difference can *also* change the month and year figures, if the current culture uses a non-Gregorian calendar.

See the [MSDN page on custom date and time format specifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) for more details.

Are you certain that you want to fix the format for *all* cultures though? It's unfortunate that there's no way of saying "give me a culture-appropriate month-and-year format" but you at least need to be aware that it might look odd to some people.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
ViewBag.Created = d.item.StartDate.ToString(@"MM\/yyyy");
```